# Is the phrase "English Spoken Classes" correct?

Tags: grammar, past-participles

I saw an advert for "English Spoken Classes". While reading it, I thought that it was incorrect and should instead read "English Speaking Classes". A quick search on Google returned results for "Spoken English Classes".

Is the phrase correct?

Comment: no, it would be "Spoken English Classes".  You were correct.

Comment: "English speaking classes" could simply mean courses that are taught in English... but aren't necessarily about the English language.

Comment: Good thing it wasn't "English Written Classes"!

Comment: The question is unclear. Is the reference to 1) classes (potentially covering any subject area) that are delivered in English, or to 2) classes which are designed to improve the students' command of spoken English? Until you have cleared up whether you are referring to 1) or 2), any answers to your question will be based on guessing what you meant.

Comment: @erik It refers to point 2; i.e. the classes are designed to improve

Comment: It's hard to tell what the intent is.  It could simply be localized "shorthand" for classes (in, eg, math) where speaking English is allowed.  If it's supposed to be an ad for a class which teaches one how to speak English, though, run the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

The most unambiguous wording for your intended meaning (thanks for clarifying, BTW) is "Classes in spoken English". Any other variant can be interpreted in more than one way.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with *English Speaking Classes* (this has the same meaning as *Spoken English Classes*).

*English* is an adjective that describes the type of *speaking*, and *speaking* is an adjective that describes the type of *classes*.

For the words *English spoken* to make any sense at all, you'd have to insert a colon (or possibly something similar) in the middle to connect the words: *English: spoken*.